# How do I create rabbitmq.conf volume in Dcoker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I've been working on a Spring Boot project that uses RabbitMQ as a dev tool to create domain events. For that, I decided to use docker compose to let the people that download my code use the same tools that I used to make the project work.

The problem that i have is in my rabbitmq.conf file, when I run `docker compose up` Docker Desktop shows the following:

```
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
touch: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf: I/O error
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2.7"
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb/server
    container_name: tour_system_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MARIADB_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
  queue_management:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    container_name: tour_system_mq
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${RABBITMQ_PORT}:5672"
      - "${RABBITMQ_GUI_PORT}:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
      - ./volumes/rabbitmq/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
      - ./volumes/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

And this is what I have inside my local `rabbitmq.conf`:

```
loopback_users.guest = false

rabbitmq_management.load_definitions = "etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"
```

Am I failing in something when i create my volumes or this is an error from docker?

Thanks.

Comment: RabbitMQ 3.8.X is completely out of support. This isn't related to your issue, but you should not use such an old version.

Comment: Based on the error, there is something wrong with the filesystem or storage that is backing the `./volumes` directory on your host, or of course there is a docker problem. Does MariaDB start up successfully? On your host, can you run `touch ./volumes/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` successfully? What host OS and version are you using?

Comment: Hi Luke, Yes, MariaDB runs perfectly and I'm running Windows 11 Pro with Docker version 20.10.17

Comment: `docker run --interactive --tty --entrypoint=/bin/bash --volume C:/path/to/volumes/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf rabbitmq:3-management` then in the container run `ls -la /etc/rabbitmq`. What is the output? Really though it would be best to continue the discussion on the mailing list - https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users